# Send array to rank with order

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have some processes. Each process has an array "A" expect from rank 0 where expect of array A has an array B as well.

I need each process to send the A array to the B array of rank 0. I need the send and receive to be done in order, that is, first rank 0 to send the contents of the array A to B, then rank 1, rank 2 etc.

My problem is that, each array A does not have the same size! Here is the part of my code that try to do that:

```
   if(my_rank!=0)
   {
      MPI_Send(&A, Asize, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }

   if(my_rank==0)
   {
      for(i=1; i<number_of_process; i++)
      {
         MPI_Recv(&B, n, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      }
   }
```

I need to then to transfer the contents from rank0 A to B as is the only one that is not transferred. Unfortunately this gives run time error:

```
=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

Array Declaration:

```
int *A = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int)*n );
int *B = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int)*n );
```

But array A some times is less than n in size.

Comment: What about A and B:  are they arrays (`int A[xxx];`) or are they pointers (`int *A`) ?  Can you show how you allocate them ?

Comment: Hey, yes I will update my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

The functions [`MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/) both expect as parameter a pointer to the region containing your data:

You give them the address of the pointer itself (i.e. `&A`) and not the address of the region (i.e.pointed by the value of `A`).  As a result the pointer will be overwritten and the stack will be corrupted, hence your segmentation fault.

Correct as follows:

```
  MPI_Send(A, Asize, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  // no &
  ...
  MPI_Recv(B, n, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);  // no &
```

Comment: correct. this now avoids the run time error but still I am not getting the correct order.

Comment: `0, rank`  are you sure it shouldn't be `rank,0` ?  And have you checked the error code returned by these functins ?

Comment: By the definition of the MPI_Send:
`buf
,count
,datatype
,dest
,tag
,comm`
So it looks that the rank is 0 and then the tag.

Comment: Ok ! What do you mean with  *"not getting the correct order"* ? Could you explain also if you move every B you receive to somewhere else, or if you expect B to contain all the received data from all the sening processes ?

Comment: Lets assume that P0 A = 1, 2, 3 and P1 A = 4,5,6,7,9 I am expecting to get in P0 B = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 but the number are not in the right order sometimes the whole range is not in order, or the P2 comes first rather than first P1

Comment: I'm not sure that you follow the right way here:  as the sending size can vary,  I'd expect that you check length received with `MPI_Get_count()`. And the numbers received should always start to bee stored at the begin of B, overwriting its content.  So I'd expect that either you use some offset to B, or that you copy (concatenation) B into a larger array at the correct offset.